# Buenas tardes, solicito ayuda con éste problema de sucesión de fibonacci en java

Tags: fibonacci

Después de la muerte de su hijo, el rey Iadava cayó en una profunda tristeza. En un intento por sacar al rey de su depresión, Sissa Ben Dahir, brahmán asesor del rey, le enseñó a éste a jugar ajedrez. Tal fue la efectividad del juego, que el rey decidió recompensar a Sissa con lo que éste le pidiera. Sissa hizo una petición muy simple: por el primer cuadro del tablero, quería que le entregarán un grano de trigo, por el segundo dos, por el tercero cuatro, por el cuarto ocho, y así, por cada cuadro deberían pagarle el doble de lo pagado por el anterior.

Para ayudarse, reflexione acerca de cada una de las siguientes preguntas: a. ¿Cuántos granos de trigo deben pagarse a Sissa por los primeros diez cuadros? b. ¿Cómo se puede calcular fácilmente el pago que debe hacerse a Sissa por los primeros n cuadros si se conoce el pago por n-1 cuadros?

Escriba un método recursivo en lenguaje java que retorne el número de granos de trigo que deben ser entregados a Sissa dado el número de cuadros, n, que representa los primeros cuadros del tablero.

Comment: Agrega lo que lleves por favor, dado que al ser solo el enunciado de una tarea sin mayor contexto pudiera terminar cerrada, checa aquí [ask]

Comment: Adicional a esto, la categoria de la pregunta es errada, el problema no tiene nada que ver con `fibonacci`, Juan, para este problema le recomiendo que lea el libro "El Hombre que Calculaba"